# how can i show actual source code in a div

Tags: php, jquery, html

i want to show a part of my source code with color coding in a div for allowing users to get reference of code..now how can i show the actual php jquery or any other language source code with colors in a div.

Comment: jQuery isn't a language. jQuery is a Framework based on the JavaScript Language

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [SyntaxHighlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/wiki/SyntaxHighlighter)

Comment: You're linke doesn't work. I think you meant this one: http://code.google.com/p/syntaxhighlighter/?

Comment: that's funny, now it's working for me too. Just 2 min ago it was a link to http://SyntaxHighlighter/

Comment: @Jens I fixed it within seconds - you were faster I guess. And yeah, the link you posted has a link to Alex's page that I posted.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [geshi](http://qbnz.com/highlighter/) for that.

Answer (score 0):

I quite like [Alex Gorbatchev's javascript-based syntax highlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/wiki/SyntaxHighlighter). It's very easy to integrate with existing CMS or blogging software (because it's just a javascript library) and produces nice output as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to output php, you could also use the built-in functions for that:

- [highlight_string()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.highlight-string.php)
- [highlight_file()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.highlight-file.php)