# Show and style HTML source code in HTML page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to display HTML source code in an HTML page. So I want it to look like it looks in your text editor. The source will be the complete source code, from the `<html>` tag to the end. So it needs to include the `<head>` and `<body>` with all styles in the `<head>`.

How would I do this?

Comment: Take a look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70169/how-to-highlight-source-code-in-html

Comment: check this: http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/manual/demo/ , source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3090762/how-can-i-show-actual-source-code-in-a-div

Answer (score 2):

```
<textarea name="Source Code"></textarea>
```

then set the value of that text area to

```
document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML
```

You might need to add the html tags again. But that should be no problem

### Edit 2018

Someone upvoted this. I would highly recommend you take a look at https://highlightjs.org/. Its a very good solution for the stated problem.